# Browser will not allow to save larger canvas size- Fabric js

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Here, we are working with **fabric.js** and creating a design tool. We just set **`canvas width and canvas height more than "10000px" .`** for example, we assume that **`canvas width and height 8640px x10800px (96" inches x 120" inches) and 2160px x 5400px ( 24 x 60 inches ) and so on`**.

We are especially facing issues related to the browser:

> google chrome results **"Aw , Snap !"** issues while saving many object
>   (like rectangle, circle, Image, Text) and Internet explorer showns "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation".

[image: Google Chrome error]

What are the issues and how to resolve it? We are facing that problem only in large canvas resolution size.

Comment: Are you sure you need all that size?  Screen resolution won't go that high, so most of it is wasted.  You could try scalping the canvas with CSS or scrolling on a smaller canvas.

Comment: Yes am sure.We have tried to scalping the canvas with css and reduce canvas size with transformation CSS option. High resolution canvas will not allow to save and execute in fabric js